# Devise user paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controllers

I am using devise for my auth and it works great. I need a profile page and I created a controller for `Users` and have a `show` method in there which links to `show.html.erb` and that works once the id is passed.

I want to add a link in the profile to go to the url `/users/[:id]` but I can't get it to work. I've tried:

```
match 'users/:id', :to 'users#show', :as => :profile
```

but I get error saying no action show.

Can anyone give me some advice to get a link to route to their profile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want something to go /users/:id isn't it as simple as:

routes.rb

```
resources :users
```

view_file.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Bob's profile", user_path(user_id) %>
```

Comment: I tried that but get undefined local variable or method `user_id' for #<#<Class:0x007fd19c487e78>:0x007fd19c13e870> 

I have resources :users

Comment: the user_id is the id you'd want to use. So, whose `id` do you want to see? If you want the current_user's profile you'd do it like <%= link_to current_user.name, user_path(current_user.id) %> Please keep in mind I'm making assumptions about the objects/attributes you have available.

Comment: please note, if you use the example above it would be `profile_path(current_user.id)`

Answer (score 0):

Your route should be

```
match 'users/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => :profile
                      ^^^^
```

Comment: @user1995600 If you remove the "as..." ?

Comment: class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def show 
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end
end